# How can I cut a string after a specific character?

Tags: php

I want to cut my path always after the searched string:

```
$subject = "katze/123pferd/123hase/tier/affe/berg";
$search = "affe";

$pos = strpos($subject, $search);
if ($pos !== false) {
    $result = substr($subject, 0, strpos($subject, '/', $pos));
}

echo $result;
```

This is working fine, if I have the element only once inside my path.

For example the case `$search = "affe"` the result is `katze/123pferd/123hase/tier/affe`

For the case `$search = "tier"` the result is `katze/123pferd/123hase/tier`

For the case `$search = "hase"` the result is `katze/123pferd/123hase`

BUT if I have the case `$search = "123"` the result is `katze/123pferd` although it should be `katze/123pferd/123hase`.

Comment: you can do it using a foreach loop.

Comment: So what is your expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

> use `strpos` for checking the worst cases. like `123`.

```
$subject = "katze/123pferd/123hase/tier/affe/berg";
$search = "affe";

$arr = explode("/", $subject);
$out = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    $out[] = $val;
    if($val == $search || strpos($val, $search) !== false)
        break;      
}
echo implode("/", $out); //katze/123pferd/123hase/tier/affe

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => katze
    [1] => 123pferd
    [2] => 123hase
    [3] => tier
    [4] => affe
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

    $subject = "katze/123pferd/123hase/tier/affe/berg";
    $search = "affe";
    echo get_string($subject,$search);

    function get_string($subject,$search){
        $arr = (explode("/",$subject));
        $key = array_search($search, $arr);
        $newrr = array_slice($arr,0,$key+1,true);
        return implode("/",$newrr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strrpos` to find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string:

```
$subject = "katze/123pferd/123hase/tier/affe/berg";
$search = "123";

$pos = strrpos($subject, $search);
if ($pos !== false) {
    $result = substr($subject, 0, strpos($subject, '/', $pos));
}

print_r($result);   // "katze/123pferd/123hase"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php